NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ya
Not able to find the issues since all the services are injected and added in providers array? What could be the issues any help?

NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ya!     at
Rs.get (main.js:23:56342)     at bl.get (main.js:23:65575)     at
bl.get (main.js:23:65575)     at Hm.get (main.js:23:118959)     at Ip
(main.js:23:75742)     at kp (main.js:23:76236)     at Object.vd
(main.js:23:96109)     at Re.#e.ɵf

I have checked all the services used in the component and all the services used in the component are properly injected . Able to run the application and after running its stucks at white screen
